# duplicate left sidebar content sections

Tags: magento-enterprise, rwd-theme

Please help me. I don't know why it has 2 "Compare Products" and "My Orders" inside user dashboard. Can you help me to figure it out what template should I check?

I'm using Magento Enterprise 1.14 and RWD Theme

[image]

Thank you in advanced

Comment: provide relevant codes? or share when it starts to seem, what did you recently do etc

Comment: These blocks are being called twice somewhere in layout xml files, you need to cross check all the associated layout xml files and delete the extra code(which is making blocks appear twice).

Comment: Hi Anshu, yes you're right. I already figure it out 30minutes ago :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer guys but I already figure it out of myself. Although Amit gave me a bit hint for that.

it's under 2 xml files.

For the Compare Products, its under

> customer.xml

Find this code. Under it has a block. Just find it, and comment it OUT!

```
 <customer_account translate="label">

   <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>

 </customer_account>
```

For the My Order, it's under

> sales.xml

I just comment this code

```
<customer_account>

    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="sales/reorder_sidebar" name="sale.reorder.sidebar" as="reorder" template="sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</customer_account>
```

and that's it! NO MORE DUPLICATING SECTIONS.

Hope this will be helpful on the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

local.xml if exits at(app/design/frontend/rwd/defult/layout/)
add below code

```
<customer_account translate="label">
  <reference name="left">

        <remove name="tags_popular"/>
         <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    </reference>
```

if local.xml then full code  at(app/design/frontend/rwd/defult/layout/)
add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account translate="label">
      <reference name="left">

            <remove name="tags_popular"/>
             <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/>
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your reply. I actually tried the second code on local.xml, it works but all of them was gone. hehe

Comment: Alyssa Reyes,please accept annswer

Comment: Alyssa Reyes, ,please accept my answer by right sign(correct sign )